# Mapping the external api request based on a pattern from a general request

Tags: c#, api, request-mapping

I have an application with a general search request which has an identification number that could be anything like product number or customer number along with additional search criteria. I want to display all the results. I am writing a middleware to call the search api end points.

```
public class GeneralRequest
    {
        public string IdentificationNumber { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime Stop { get; set; }
    }

public class AdditionalSearch
    {
        public RangeSearch Range { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }      
    }

  public class RangeSearch
    {
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime Stop { get; set; }
    }

public class GetProductRequest : AdditionalSearch, ISearchRequest
    {
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
    }

public class GetCustomerRequst : AdditionalSearch, ISearchRequest
    {
        public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    }

public class GetManufacturerRequest : AdditionalSearch, ISearchRequest
    {
        public string ManufacturerNumber { get; set; }
    }
// this is a dummy interface to make all the requests general
public interface ISearchRequest
    {
    }
```

This is the searchprocessor where I am creating the correct request based on the identification number pattern. But I am failing to assign the AdditonalSearch to the request that I get after invoking the func. Of course it is an interface that has nothing in it. How can I achieve this by not repeating(I mean I don't want to repeat the initialization logic in the dictionary)
Please suggest me what is the best practice here.

```
public class SearchProcessor
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Regex, Func<GeneralRequest, ISearchRequest>> _pattern;
        private readonly IAppClient _appClient;

        public SearchProcessor(IAppClient appClient)
        {
            _appClient = appClient;
            _pattern = new Dictionary<Regex, Func<GeneralRequest, ISearchRequest>>
            {
                {new Regex("/\b([0-9]|10)\b /"), p=> new GetProductRequest(){ProductId = p.IdentificationNumber} },
                {new Regex("^\\d{}1,9}$"), p=> new GetCustomerRequst(){CustomerNumber = p.IdentificationNumber} },
                {new Regex("^\\d{}1,11}$"), p=> new GetManufacturerRequest(){ManufacturerNumber = p.IdentificationNumber} }
            };
            
        }

        public List<SearchResult> GetAllSearchResults(GeneralRequest request)
        {

            var requests = _pattern.Where(r => r.Key.IsMatch(request.IdentificationNumber)).Select(v => v.Value);

            var responses = new List<SearchResult>();
            foreach (var req in requests)
            {
                var appRequest = req.Invoke(request);
                
                appRequest.AdditionalSearch = new AdditionalSearch // this is where I am not able to assign the additional seach from the general request
                {
                    Range = new RangeSearch { Start = request.Start, Stop = request.Stop}
                    IsActive = request.IsActive,
                    Location = request.Location
                };
              //This calls another api to get the response.
                responses.Add(_appclient.FindResult(appRequest));
            }
            return responses;
        }
    }
```

---UPDATE--
Here is the appclient that calls the external api..

sample request for the getproduct route is

```
public class AppClient : IAppClient
{

    private readonly string _baseurl;

    private readonly string _getProductRoute;
    private readonly string _getCustomerRoute;
    private readonly string _getManufacturerRoute;

    public AppClient()
    {
        _getProductRoute = $"{_baseurl}/api/get-product";
        _getCustomerRoute = $"{_baseurl}/api/get-customer";
        _getManufacturerRoute = $"{_baseurl}/api/get-Manufacturer";
    }
    public SearchResult FindResult(ISearchRequest searchRequest)
    {
        var routes = new Dictionary<Type, string>
        {
            {typeof(GetProductRequest), _getProductRoute },
            {typeof(GetCustomerRequst), _getCustomerRoute },
            {typeof(GetManufacturerRequest), _getManufacturerRoute }
        };
        // Here it is going to be http implementation to call above routes.
        return new SearchResult();
    }
}
```

The request for get product route is

```
{
   "ProductId":"",
   "RangeSearch":{
      "Start":"",
      "Stop":""
   },
   "Location":"",
   "IsActive":true
}
```

For get-customer request is

```
{
   "CustomerNumber":"",
   "RangeSearch":{
      "Start":"",
      "Stop":""
   },
   "Location":"",
   "IsActive":true
}
```

Comment: could you provide a sample on the api endpoints to see how things work outside your middleware. Understanding the api will help us evaluating your work, and give a better help.

Comment: I updated my post with how the api will be called.. hope that make sense.. I removed unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your work by doing this :

```
public class SearchRequest
{
    public string IdentificationNumber { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public SearchRequestRange Range { get; set; }

    public SearchRequest(string identificationNumber)
    {
        IdentificationNumber = identificationNumber;
    }
}

public class SearchRequestRange
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Stop { get; set; }
}
```

now the process you are doing is not needed, you only need to adjust your `ApiClient` to something like this  :

```
public class AppClient : IAppClient
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> _endPointsSearchPatterns = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"get-product", "/\b([0-9]|10)\b /"},
        {"get-customer", "^\\d{}1,9}$"},
        {"get-Manufacturer", "^\\d{}1,11}$"}
    };
    
    private readonly string _baseUrl;

    public AppClient(string baseUrl) 
    { 
        if(string.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace(baseUrl))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(baseUrl));
        
        _baseurl = baseUrl;
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<SearchResult> FindResult(SearchRequest searchRequest)
    {
        var endPoints = _endPointsSearchPatterns.Where(x=> Regex.IsMatch(request.IdentificationNumber , x.Value))?.ToList();
        
        if(endPoints?.Count == 0)
        {
            yield break;
        }
            
        var responses = new List<SearchResult>();
        
        foreach(var endpoint in endPoints)
        {           
            ISearchBy search = null;

            switch(endPoint.Key)
            {
                case "get-product":
                    action = new ProductApiClient(this);
                    break;
                case "get-customer":
                    action = new ProductApiClient(this);
                    break;
                case "get-Manufacturer":
                    action = new ProductApiClient(this);                    
                    break;              
            }
            
            yield return action.SearchBy(searchRequest); 
            
        }
        
        return searchResult;
    }
}
```

Regarding `GetProductRequest`, `GetCustomerRequst`, and `GetManufacturerRequest` these should be refactored, and instead you can create a class for each entity like this :

```
public interface ISearchBy
{
    SearchResult ISearchBy(SearchRequest request);
}

public class ProductApiClient : ISearchBy
{
    private readonly IAppClient _appClient;
    public ProductApiClient(IAppClient appClient)
    {
        _appClient = appClient; 
    }
    
    public SearchResult SearchBy(SearchRequest request)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    
    // other related endpoints 
}


public class CustomerApiClient : ISearchBy
{
    private readonly IAppClient _appClient;
    public CustomerApiClient(IAppClient appClient)
    {
        _appClient = appClient; 
    }
    
    public SearchResult SearchBy(SearchRequest request)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    
    // other related endpoints 
}

public class ManufacturerApiClient : ISearchBy
{
    private readonly IAppClient _appClient;
    public ManufacturerApiClient(IAppClient appClient)
    {
        _appClient = appClient; 
    }
    
    public SearchResult SearchBy(SearchRequest request)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    
    // other related endpoints 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But from your solution the request is not changed,, the request is different for each endpoint. Product Request has productId', Customer request has Customernumber

Comment: @alienavatar I have updated my answer